How does Py4J single-threading model work with FastAPI in a high-concurrency scenario?
I’m integrating Py4J with a FastAPI application where multiple concurrent API requests need to communicate with a Java application. I’ve read the Py4J single-threading model documentation, but I have questions about connection management:

Does the client_server.jvm object always use the same thread for requests originating from a single Python thread? If so, does this behavior persist when multiple FastAPI requests share the same client_server instance?

client_server = ClientServer(java_parameters=JavaParameters(address=remote_host))
client_server.shutdown_callback_server()


Is it better to share a single ClientServer instance across requests, or should I create a new instance for each request? Would a connection pool with multiple ClientServer instances improve performance in high-concurrency scenarios?

If I reuse the client_server instance in FastAPI across multiple requests, does it retain any persistent resources (e.g., imports, variables) between calls that could cause issues? If the same FastAPI thread is reused for a future request, does the import remain, or how is it collected by GC? Are there any risks of conflicts when the same ClientServer instance is reused for multiple requests?


jvm = client_server.jvm
java_import(jvm, "<java class>")

If the same FastAPI thread handles a future request, does the import remain? How is it managed by the garbage collector? Are there risks of conflicts with reused ClientServer instances?
Any advice on making this setup scalable and performant would be greatly appreciated!
